# $Branch is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: powershell, branch, dnx, terminator

I'm trying to instal DVNM using this tutorial (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sujitdmello/2015/04/23/step-by-step-installation-instructions-for-getting-dnx-on-your-windows-machine/).

I did it on other notebook with Win10, I'm 8.1 embedded here and first script get me error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

'{$Branch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone to solve my problem? No solution wherever I search  and I'm stack now...

Comment: isn't it a bit old -- they did make some changes if I remember correctly

Comment: DNX and DNVM have been replaced by the new .NET CLI. See: https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem, but I will leave this thread on stack. Cmd sucks, I did install by powershell just using commend to parse:

```
&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}
```